# UIPicker swipes not responding

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

UIPicker swipes where responding perfectly in the Iphone simulator with SDK 2.2, but i am now testing with a new version of the simulator, and swipes are not working. I went trough the documentation and i cant see any changes on the API. So im asumming that something is wrong and the SDK 2.2 is letting me get away with it.

The Picker uses custom views to display an image and text beside it. The picker does change position correctly when you do a single tap on a row of the Picker. But if you try to swipe it does not respond (sometimes it moves a few millimeters). I thought the custom view for each row was not letting the picker detect the swipes, so i added self.userInteractionEnabled = NO in the custom view, but it hasn't made any difference.

Your help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Are you now using SDK 2.2.1 or 3.0? If the latter, which beta?

Comment: Is your UIPicker inside a UIScrollView? If so, you might need to set the UIScrollView.scrollEnabled to NO in order to see the swiping return - I just solved this with some helps here.

Comment: Yes, the UIPicker is inside a UIScrollView! Your solution works (Add it so i can accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the UIPicker is inside a UIScrollView. To fix it set the UIScrollView.scrollEnabled to NO in order to see the swiping return.